# What about AD2P vulnerability?

Tags: windows, linux, bluetooth

My goal is to create a simple one-way intercom using *B Speech TX2* and *B Speech RX2*, an Audio2Bluetooth and Bluetooth2Audio converter.

My question is, how secure is the audio(in my case voice) being transmitted via AD2P using this setup? Can other people in bt-range easily listen to what I say?

Or in other words: How do I test it for vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth 2.1 and forward require encryption on all connections other than service discovery.  A key is exchanged during pairing and used for all future service delivery.  If your hardware is using a standard prior to 2.1, then it is possible it could use an unencrypted connection, but otherwise it is guaranteed to use encryption.

In fact, the NSA has even has a [post](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/factsheets/I732-016R-07.pdf) that says they have found it secure enough for unclassified government use, so they don't see any critical flaws in the encryption.  So as long as you use encrypted connections, you should be secure.  The chances of a sufficiently advanced attacker to be able to hook in to it are pretty much non-existent if used and paired properly.

Comment: According to the specs it's Bluetooth V. 2.0, class II

Comment: How do I test it for vulnerabilities?

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength - I'm not even sure how you would begin.  You could try connecting with a device that isn't paired and see if you can discover or pair, but really, I think you'd need some kind of broad spectrum receiver to try to pull the raw information out of the air.  I don't really think testing for vulnerabilities is all that viable on an individual's budget.  Maybe someone else knows of a bluetooth radio that can do it, but I think they use frequency hoping that would make it a challenge.

Comment: You said that only starting from bt 2.1 it was safe and below it might not be. So I need to know hoe to test this.

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength - oh, I see, it's a BT2.0 Class 2 device, so you aren't sure if it is encrypted or not.  Sorry, didn't understand what you were looking for.  I'll do a little digging and see what I can find for you.

Comment: @PeakReconstructionWavelength - I would hazard that those devices may very well be able to be eavesdropped on from up to a mile away.  They are class 2 devices and make no mention of using the encryption that was optional (and had known weaknesses) in the V2.0 spec.

Comment: Any ideas on why this post got downvoted?

Comment: How do I test it for vulnerabilities? Which tools do I use under linux or windows?